# MVC Entity Framework Razor Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have to following code and there's a problem and I can't figure out what's the problem. Well, I have two ideas about the place where the problem may appear but I can't find a solution.

The problem is that my layout is rendered twice.

Layout.cshtml

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left_side"> @RenderPage("left_side.cshtml") </div>   
    <div id="center_side"> @RenderBody() </div>
    <div id="right_side"> @RenderPage("right_side.cshtml") </div>
</div>
```

left_side.cshtml

```
@if (ViewBag.LeftColumnVisible == true)
{
    @Html.Action("GetCategories", "Products");
}
```

GetCategories method from Products controller

```
public ActionResult GetCategories()
{
   List<Categories> categories = db.Categories.ToList();
   ...

   return View();
}
```

**GetCategories.cshtml**

```
@foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry de in ViewBag.LeftColumnContent)
{
    <div> @((Ads.Models.Categories)(de.Key)).Name; </div>
}
```

It enters the get categories and renders the content.

The problem for rendering twice may be at this line
`@Html.Action("GetCategories", "Products");` or when it calls View(). If I comment the line, my layout will be rendered only once.

Comment: Is `GetCategories` supposed to be a partial view?

Comment: Yes, it's a kind of helper. I render the categories there and then I get the result in the left side which will be passed to the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say there are a couple of issues with your code. First of all, if `left_side.cshtml`/`right_side.cshtml` are *partial* views then you want to be using

```
@Html.RenderPartial("view")
```

to render them and not `@RenderPage` - although `@RenderPage` will work it's better from a readability point of view to understand exactly what the type of view it is you are working with.

Secondly, if your `GetCategories` view is a partial view you want to be returning a `PartialView` and not a `View` i.e.

```
public ActionResult GetCategories()
{
    ...
    return PartialView();
}
```